# Strong encryption algorithms are not supported in syncfusion XlsIO

Tags: c#, syncfusion

During sheet creation i have set password like below:

```
 workbook.Worksheets[1].Protect("123");
 workbook.Protect(false, true, "123");
 workbook.Version = ExcelVersion.Excel97to2003;
```

And trying to read as below:

```
ExcelEngine excelEngine = null;
IApplication application = null;
IWorkbook workbook = null;
IWorksheet sheet = null;
... ...
excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
application = excelEngine.Excel;
workbook = excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation, ExcelOpenType.Automatic);
```

But shows message like **Strong encryption algorithms are not supported**.
I tried using

```
workbook = excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation,ExcelParseOptions.Default,false,"123",ExcelOpenType.Automatic);
```

Even using the below code it is not working:

```
application.OnPasswordRequired += application_OnPasswordRequired;
void application_OnPasswordRequired(object sender, PasswordRequiredEventArgs e)
        {
            e.NewPassword = "123";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion XlsIO does not have support for strong encryption algorithms and do not have immediate plans to implement this in near future.

We request you to look into https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/security, for various options of protection.